# What is the difference between Charset.defaultCharset() and file.encoding?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I run Java SE 8 on MS Windows 7 and use both Eclipse and Netbeans. By running the following program, I realized that the return values of each of the two expressions are different!

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
System.out.printf(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

While about Charset.defaultCharset() it's said that "Returns the default charset", and about file.encoding we are told that "The default charset is kept in the JVM's system property file.encoding". So, it seems that Charset.defaultCharset() must return exactly what stored in file.encoding. But I realized that it  doesn't happen!! For example, if I change file.encoding content by

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", "Big5");
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

It prints Big5, but

```
System.out.printf(Charset.defaultCharset());
```

still print its previous value (on Eclipse it prints Windows-1256 and in Netbeans it prints UTF-8). Can you please explain what exactly they are and what relation and difference they have in practice.

---

Edition: After a while I found very useful contents about this subject in this site and the whole problem was solved:

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-set-default-character-encoding.html?m=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you are getting form `Charset.defaultCharset()` is what the JVM was started with. It cannot be changed afterwards.

System properties, on the other hand, can be changed but whether you get the desired effect in various JDK classes is a different matter.

In order to use a different charset, it's better to provide a JVM argument, such as

```
java -cp <classpath> <package.classname> -Dfile.encoding=Big5
```

Comment: Thank you Jaywalker, but I can't understand difference between the JVM charset and the charset that it use for a program. Suppose JVM started with UTF-8, if we set file.encoding to some other charset, then where in a Java program this UTF-8 charset (JVM charset) take a role?

Comment: Input stream reader and corresponding writer classes would take an extra parameter where you can specify the encoding. Why not use that? Default character set is just that - it's default when you don't specify anything.